# Cheap way to get to Argentina

Tags: tickets, budget, russia, argentina

Does anyone know a cheap (or at least not very expensive) way to get from Russia (Moscow) to Argentina? I want to visit that country, but tickets  are way to much expensive. I use skyscanner now, maybe I should manually look for tickets with transition in some specific countries?

Comment: Are there some restrictions as to what time you can go? Or how long you want to visit for?

Comment: I'm going to Bariloche (Patagonia). I want to go in October at least, when the weather there is better. For a couple of months.

Comment: I found DME-BRC flights from руб. 101 221 (USD 1576) return. This doesn't seem unreasonable. At least from outside Russia. But the ruble is weaker now than it has been even a few years ago.

Comment: Unfortunately, inside of Russia it's very unreasonable.

Comment: It would be better of you share your travel-mode options as well or do you want to use flights only?

Comment: I think, I don't have other options, I'll need to cross the ocean, and I don't know if I can travel through Europe on a train or bus without a visa.

Comment: There is probably no cheap way to get there.  It's very far.

Comment: Maybe just some travel-hacks? For example, I know, that if you want to go to China it will be a lot cheaper to go to Finland, and go to China from there, than to go from Moscow. Yeah, it won't be a very comfy trip, but less expensive. So maybe there's something similar with South America

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have time restriction then I'd suggest to get Schengen visa and travel most of the way in Europe by land.

In Europe you can find really cheap night long distance buses (even starting from 1 EUR if you booking in advance, have some patience and a good luck) ,and this lets you don't pay for hostel. Blablacar is also much cheaper than flights.

I have no experience in South America, so cannot say about that part.

Right now I see $430 from Salvador (Brasilia) to Valencia, whilst Buenos-Aires to Moscow is ~$800.

For the same time period: 
Brigetown-Kaunas $388 (check visas!)
Sao-Paulo-Valencia $346
Sao-Paulo-Moscow $513

Comment: Traveling by car from Sao Paulo to Buenos Aires is a 27 hour drive; you can't take a night bus. Distances are not the same as in Europe; both Argentina and Brazil span the territory of several european countries. If you are doing this, I recommend you fly from Brazil to Argentina.

Answer (score 5):

We've used Moscow-Dubai, Dubai-Rio-Buenos Aires route using Emirates I believe and price was tolerable as these things go - ~35 000 rub one way per person a year ago. Our return flight was from Peru and considerably more expensive (900 euro/person via Panama and Frankfurt)

Via skyscanner I believe.

Comment: And indeed skyscanner offers tickets like these for ~40k rub targetting October

Comment: Thanks! I'll check today. Last time I checked, saw only 70k+ tickets via Rome

Comment: @airbear if 70k+ happens to be two-way then it's a steal.